# Drawing pyramid using recursion

Tags: python, class, recursion

I want to create a pyramid class recursively using cs1graphics. This class would allow user to specify the number of levels and the overall width of the pyramid.

cs1graphics module: https://github.com/otfried/cs101/blob/master/modules/cs1graphics.py

I can do this using for loop but I don't know how to use recursion to achieve the same things.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from cs1graphics import *

numLevels = 8
unitSize = 12
screenSize = unitSize * (numLevels + 1)
paper = Canvas(screenSize, screenSize)

centerX = screenSize / 2.0

for level in range(numLevels):
   centerY = (level + 1) * unitSize
   leftmostX = centerX - unitSize * level / 2.0
   for blockCount in range(level + 1):
       block = Square(unitSize)
       block.move(leftmostX + unitSize * blockCount, centerY)
       block.setFillColor('gray')
       paper.add(block)
```

This is my attempt:

```
class Pyramid(Drawable):
    def __init__(self, numLevels, unitSize):
        screenSize = self.unitSize * (self.numLevels + 1)
        paper = Canvas(screenSize, screenSize)
        centerX = screenSize / 2.0
```

I don't know how to complete the rest of class.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's good that you can do it iteratively, but can you also share your attempt at doing it recursively? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the post. But i don't think I've shown much. I know I have create a base case somewhere but don't know how.

Comment: OK, that's a start but doesn't really contain any recursive logic. You might start by creating a `draw` function that generates one block. Then try changing the parameters a bit and having this `draw` function call itself. The base case has to stop recursion at some point to avoid blowing the stack. If the pyramid is too complex, simplify the problem to just drawing a line recursively with, say, 5 blocks in a row, then build on the techniques you learned.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this.

Comment: Good luck. One additional suggestion: if working with graphics is getting in the way of understanding recursion, try working with simple text problems, like printing the numbers 1-10 recursively, then do it backwards. Then try Fibonacci numbers, etc. Then go back to the suggestions above related to graphics.

Comment: Thanks. Graphics is indeed getting in the way. I'll try without it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work: 
In your init, store all the info as class variables, and call a recursive function that updates the current level. When the level hits a basecase (eg hits 0 if you are counting down, or numLevels if you are counting up as here) then stop recursing.

```
from cs1graphics import *
class Pyramid(Drawable):
    def __init__(self, numLevels, unitSize):
      self.numLevels = numLevels
      self.currentlevel = 0
      self.unitSize = unitSize
      self.screenSize = unitSize * (numLevels + 1)
      self.paper = Canvas(screenSize, screenSize)
      self.centerX = screenSize / 2.0
      self.draw_pyramid()

    def draw_pyramid(self):
       centerY = (self.currentlevel + 1) * self.unitSize
       leftmostX = self.centerX - self.unitSize * self.currentlevel / 2.0
       for blockCount in range(self.currentlevel + 1):
         block = Square(self.unitSize)
         block.move(leftmostX + self.unitSize * blockCount, centerY)
         block.setFillColor('gray')
         self.paper.add(block)
       self.currentlevel += 1
       if self.currentlevel == self.numLevels:
         return
       self.draw_pyramid()
```